# Proving $g:P\to\Bbb R, g(x)=3x+2$ is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, cantor-set

> Define $g:P\to\Bbb R,g(x)=3x+2$ where $P$ is the Cantor set. Show that $g$ can't be continuous under Euclidean metric in $\Bbb R$.

No information is given about the metric on $P$. I assumed it is the Euclidean metric. Then $g^{-1}((a,b))=\left(\frac{a-2}3,\frac{b-2}3\right)\cap P$ which is open in $P$. Then this map is continuous because the inverse image of every open set is open. In fact it seems $g$ will be continuous on any subspace of $\Bbb R$ since it is continuous on $\Bbb R$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're right if a map is continuous on $X$, it is continuous on any $A \subseteq X$ endowed with the subspace topology.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think the topology induced by Euclidean metric on $P$ is the same as the subspace topology on $P$ induced by $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean metric. Can you confirm? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I think that *maybe* they mean continuous in $\mathbb R$ and not in $P$ (if every $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ contains $x\in \mathbb R$ where $x \not \in P$ then we can't say $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$....). But that would be trivial. And stupid. And wrong.  (A function isn't a *function* outside its domain)...... So.... I have no idea what the question has in mind.... maybe they meant *must* be continuous and you were expected to show rigorous busywork of a delta epsilon proof... I dunno.

Comment: Maybe the mean it (the image of the function) can't be *connected*.... in $\mathbb R$.... *sheesh*  I really don't know.

Comment: @fleablood This question was asked verbatim in my university exam yesterday. My professors are notorious for not checking question papers for erroneous questions and sometimes it is really frustrating when one wastes time solving wrong questions. I think this could be another instance of the same.

Comment: I fear so.  Your argument and mathcounterexamples.et arguments say so.  ANd a simple delta epsilon that for all $x \in P$ so that $|x - a| < \frac \epsilon 3 \implies |(3x+2)-(3a+2)| < \epsilon$ proves that $f$ *IS* continuous at all $a \in P$.  This is freshman counter intuitive that a function that is "broken into points" it can still be continuous if the *domain* is "browen into points". But this is *classic*.  It's why *all* functions are continuous at *singleton* points in the domain.

Comment: Maybe they mean something like $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined via $g(x) := \begin{cases}3x+2 \text{ if } x \in P\\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$, which would make it a sensible exercise. But that's definitely not what they wrote there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and the question is wrong.

If we want to spell it out:

Let $a \in P$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}3$.

For all $x \in P$ so that $|x-a| < \delta$ then

$|(3x + 2) - (3a+2)|= 3|x-a| < 3\delta = \epsilon$ and so $f$ is continuous at all $a \in P$.

Can't get much more plain than that.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem** If $A\subset X$ and $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous function, then $f|A\colon A\to Y$ is continuous function.

Now, $g\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$  and $g(x)=3x+2$ is definitely continuous function. Put, $$f=g|P \ \ \ \text{for all } \  \ \ x\in P$$ So, $f\colon P\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x)=3x+2$ is continuous function by Theorem.